# Select distinct id with two types postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have orderids that can have two types and I need to select the distinct orderid where only one exists.

Data looks like:

```
orderid 1 type 1
orderid 1 type 2
orderid 2 type 1
orderid 2 type 1
```

I want to select the orderid where only type 1 exists.

I tried:

```
select distinct orderid from orders where type=1 and type<>2
```

This is returning both orderid 1 and 2

Comment: `type=1 and type<>2` this is optimized to `type=1` surely, as by definition if it equals 1 it can not equal 2 at the same time.  Both (distinct orderid) records have 1 row with type=1 so therefore it should return both ?  My 10 second look at it.

Comment: @DarrylMiles the OP only wants orderid = 2 because it doesn't have a record for type 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `except` to do this.

```
select orderid from orders where type = 1 
except
select orderid from orders where type <> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by`:

```
select orderid
from orders
group by orderid
having min(type) = 1 and max(type) = 1;
```

There is no need for `distinct`.  An `orderid` is only returned once.